# Calculate new column as the mean of other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a this data frame and I would like to calculate a new column as the mean of `salary_1`, `salary_2` and `salary_3`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'salary_1': [230, 345, 222],
    'salary_2': [235, 375, 292],
    'salary_3': [210, 385, 260]
})
```

```
      salary_1     salary_2    salary_3
0        230           235        210
1        345           375        385
2        222           292        260
```

How can I do it in pandas in the most efficient way? Actually I have many more columns and I don't want to write this one by one.

Something like this:

```
      salary_1     salary_2    salary_3     salary_mean
0        230           235        210     (230+235+210)/3
1        345           375        385       ...
2        222           292        260       ...
```

Comment: Do you want to add the result as a new column?

Comment: Yes, I want to result in a new column

Answer (score 50, accepted):

an easy way to solve this problem is shown below :

```
col = df.loc[: , "salary_1":"salary_3"]
```

where "salary_1" is the start column name and "salary_3" is the end column name

```
df['salary_mean'] = col.mean(axis=1)
df
```

**This will give you a new dataframe with a new column that shows the mean of all the other columns**
This approach is really helpful when you are having a large set of columns or also helpful when you need to perform on only some selected columns not on all.

Answer (score 85):

Use [`.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html). By specifying the axis you can take the average across the row or the column.

```
df['average'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df
```

returns

```
       salary_1  salary_2  salary_3     average
0       230       235       210  225.000000
1       345       375       385  368.333333
2       222       292       260  258.000000
```

If you only want the mean of a few you can [select only those columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). E.g.

```
df['average_1_3'] = df[['salary_1', 'salary_3']].mean(axis=1)
df
```

returns

```
   salary_1  salary_2  salary_3  average_1_3
0       230       235       210        220.0
1       345       375       385        365.0
2       222       292       260        241.0
```