# Pandas DataFrame adding of two numbers and updating it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and it looks something like this:

```
[(48500, 53500)]
[(47500, 52500)]
[(45500, 50500)]
[(40700, 45700)]
[(37500, 42500)]
[(37500, 42500)]
[(35000, 40000)]
[(32500, 37500)]
[(32500, 37500)]
[(32500, 37500)]
[(32500, 37500)]
[(32500, 37500)]
[(32500, 37500)]
[(31500, 36500)]
[(31500, 36500)]
[(30419, 35419)]
[(27500, 32500)]
[(27500, 32500)]
[(27500, 32500)]
[(27000, 32000)]
[(26500, 31500)]
[(25000, 30000)]
[(24000, 29000)]
[(23500, 28500)]
[(23420, 28420)]
[(23250, 28250)]
[(20000, 25000)]
[(17500, 22500)]
[(17000, 22000)]
```

What is the best way to add two numbers together and divide by two?

What I came up with:

```
for parent in newDf:
    for child in parent:
        print(int(child[0]) + int(child[1]) / 2.0)
```

I am certain there is a lambda function or one liner that from pandas which could make this task more simple.

Comment: [`df.mean(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate new column as the mean of other columns pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366506/calculate-new-column-as-the-mean-of-other-columns-pandas)

Comment: Thanks VladimirFokow && mkrieger1.  
I ideally wanted it it updated within the data frame and not make another frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I should off posted the whole data frame.

```
data = {
    "Salary": [(48500, 53500), (47500, 52500),(17000, 22000)],
}
```

```
df["Salary"] = df["Salary"].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))
```

Output :

```
    Salary
0  51000.0
1  50000.0
2  19500.0
```

Comment: `Salary` is two columns in one. If you split it into two columns (e.g., `df.Salary.apply(pd.Series)`), you can directly do `.mean(axis=1)` as suggested in the comments. By the way, `lambda x: func(x)` is the same as `func`, so you can simply do `.apply(np.mean)` if you don't want to restructure your data.